# Marking Radio Button checked by default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form in which i am trying to auto populate the value of radio button.

```
content=content+' <label class="radio-inline">';                
content=content+' <input type="radio" name="ip_radio_resp_'+questDetail.qId+'" id="radioYes"  value="Y" onclick="removeFocusOnComment('+questDetail.qId+');showReasonTextBox('+questDetail.qId+')"> Yes';
content=content+' </label>
```

I am checking for value for some other field, if I get the desired response I marked radio btn else not

```
switch(questDetail.metricsValue){
case 'Y':

    $('#ip_radio_resp_'+questDetail.qId).each(function() {
        $('input:radio[name="ip_radio_resp_'+questDetail.qId+'"]#radioYes').prop('checked',true);
    });
    break;
case 'N' :
    //something......   
break;
default:
    //something
}
```

I am using jquery 1.11.2

But it constantly given me error undefined..I know this can be a duplicate and I tried all other answers given, but not able to get this working...can someone please help!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try fixing your code indentation first.

Comment: Which value is undefined?

Comment: IDs must be unique per page. or the code you have is probably never going to work. The fact that you have `$('#ip_radio_resp_'+questDetail.qId).each`, when there should only ever be one item with a specific ID, is troubling.

Comment: @Franco : when I do $('input:radio[name="ip_radio_resp_'+questDetail.qId+'"]#radioYes').val(); I get undefined.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Can you please elaborate...considering I am pretty new with JQuery stuff

Comment: Have you read #Mike comment?  You can not have an id="radioYes" for all your elements.

Comment: You can't have more than one radio button with `id="radioYes"`. IDs have to be unique on the page.

Comment: i guess you need to make a radio button checked when you create them?

Comment: @AmitAgarwal you need to check my answer it will make it easier for you

Comment: @AlaaM.Jaddou thanks...i just used that approach and it worked...thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you don't need all that, you just need to check while you making you radio buttons if the

```
questDetail.metricsValue == 'Y'
```

then you need to make it checked.

you can cancel all of you switch case you create and make it this way it will be easier for you.

```
    content=content+' <label class="radio-inline">';                
    content=content+' <input type="radio" name="ip_radio_resp_'+questDetail.qId+'" class="radiosToBeChecked" id="radioYes'+questDetail.qId+'" checked="'+(questDetail.metricsValue == 'Y') ? 'checked': ''+'" onclick="removeFocusOnComment('+questDetail.qId+');showReasonTextBox('+questDetail.qId+')"> Yes';
    content=content+' </label>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `id="radioYes"` in every radio group, because IDs must be unique. Use `class="radioYes"` instead. Then you can do:

```
case 'Y':
    $('input:radio[name="ip_radio_resp_'+questDetail.qId+'"].radioYes').prop('checked',true);
    break;
```

You don't need to use `$('#ip_radio_resp_'+questDetail.qId).each` because you're not doing anything with the element with that ID (I suspect you don't even have that element, and you were confusing `name` with `id`).